# How to extract the first word after one particular word from regex

Tags: java, regex

This is the code I tried

```
public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "ddd with fff Node  preceded"
            + " by Class Application  bzxcd by " 
            + "Class aaa ds  preceded by Class bbbb xxxx Ass";

          public static void main(String[] args) {
           boolean clarrification =  EXAMPLE_TEST.matches(".*\\bClass\\b.*");


           String pattern = "(.*?\\bClass\\b.*?)(\\s+)(\\w+)";

           System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceFirst(pattern, "$3$2"));
```

What I am trying here is to only extract the first occurrence after 'Class' word. In my case it extracts the Application but it is followed by rest of the words.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simplified regex:

```
String pattern = ".*?\\bClass\\s+(\\w+)\\b.*";

System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceFirst(pattern, "$1"));
//=> Application
```

This regex matches 0 or more characters before `Class` (non-greedy) using `.*?` followed by word boundary and text `Class`. It is followed by 1 or more spaces and then next word being captured in a group#1 using `(\\w+)`. It must be followed by `.*` to match rest of the string. In the replacement we just use back-reference `$1` to get matched word back in final output.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate your solution? I am trying to learn regex.

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer.